# Drawing on XNA screen

Tags: xna-4.0, hand-drawn

I need to use Microsoft.Ink library on XNA. Previously I used ink library on winforms application and drawing on the form screen is very easy and it looks pretty good. However, when I do the same thing on the XNA screen, the ink shows up for a 1 sec then it disappears or sometimes, it shows up but flashes. Is there a solution for that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It might be easier to help if you show the code here.

Answer (score 3):

well, it has to do with the way xna works vs win forms. In xna, the screen is updated every refresh, which is by default 1/60 sec. However, win forms are only updated when they're invalidated (something changes). What I would suggest you do is draw the ink to some kind of texture and just render that every frame to the XNA window. However, I would also suggest just using the XNA framework to draw anything anyway